# Best way to create javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, creation

all i have seen creating objects like below, what is this type creating object actually?

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
```

I'm creating object like this

```
var myApp={property:"value",method:function(){}};
```

Can anybody please tell me the difference between both type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example won't replace the variable `myApp` if it already exists, and is useful for working in unfamiliar namespaces or when working with global variables. You will have to specify `myApp`'s properties after creation.

The second example will always create a new version of `myApp` and allows you to specify its properties during creation. It will override any other variables already named `myApp`.

Both examples create the same 'type' of object--there is only actually one type of object. What makes objects different from each other is the properties they possess.

Comment: thnks @Elliot Bonneville

Comment: Also note that in the first example, if `myApp` is an object, then it would behave like an object.  However, if it were `true`, any number but 0, or a string, it would behave oddly.  Basically, `myApp` could be anything truth-y, but not an actual object.

Answer (score 1):

The first example assigns a value to itself if it already has a true value, and an object with no properties otherwise.

The second example assigns an object with properties.

Comment: Hi, @quentin, what happen to first example if already an object with the same name exists.?how it wil assign properties n methods that i written for the object.?can u plz bit elaborate this

Comment: Then it will have a true value and will assign the existing value to itself and not overwrite it with a new object.

Comment: so then how can we handle such issues.?

Comment: Create a new empty object if there isn't an object already, then assign any new properties and values (to whatever object, the original or the new one, the value holds) in separate statements afterwards.

Comment: i have given piece js code to client to call our server to load js response on to the site through php,this object is the response.once loaded completly on to the site, execute the method in the object, so if this is the case, how we can handle through this new empty object, if not busy plz help me.